# FFMPEG Dropping all frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a raw H264 video which i am trying to convert into MP4 by the command:

```
ffmpeg -i 'Camera 4(172.16.2.12_554)_1_2014_07_16_15_20_08.h264' 'Camera
4(172.16.2.12_554)_1_2014_07_16_15_20_08.mp4'
```

FFMPEG keeps dropping all frames. Not even 1 frame is encoded.

Please see the output below:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate:

2400000.00 (2400000/1) -> 24.00 (24/1)

Input #0, h264, from 'Camera 4(172.16.2.12_554)_1_2014_07_16_15_20_08.h264':

Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A

Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x960 [PAR 1:1 DAR
4:3], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc

[buffer @ 0x820c140] w:1280 h:960 pixfmt:yuv420p

Output #0, mp4, to 'Camera 4(172.16.2.12_554)_1_2014_07_16_15_20_08.mp4':

Metadata:

encoder         : Lavf53.21.1

    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1280x960 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31,
200 kb/s, 24 tbn, 24 tbc

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
^Zame=    2 fps=  1 q=2.0 size=     225kB time=0.08 bitrate=22147.4kbits/s
dup=0 drop=842
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try tell to ffmpeg the fps that you desire on output file:

just type the following:

```
ffmpeg -r "24" -i 'Camera 4(172.16.2.12_554)_1_2014_07_16_15_20_08.h264' 'Camera
4(172.16.2.12_554)_1_2014_07_16_15_20_08.mp4'
```